# Is it possible to calculate the variance of a group of sets, knowing the variance of each?

Tags: statistics, variance

Set $Z$ contains 1000 numeric values.

It is split in 4 subsets $A, B, C, D$, respectively of 100, 200, 350, 350 elements.
For each subset we calculate $min, max, mean$, variance $Var, quantiles Q_{10...90}$.

Some relationship between $Z$ and the subsets are obvious:
$$min(Z) = min(min(A), min(B), min(C), min(D))$$
$$max(Z) = max(max(A), max(B), max(C), max(D))$$
$$mean(Z) = \frac{mean(A)*100 + mean(B)*200 + mean(C)*350 + mean(D)*350}{1000}$$

**Talking about variance and quantiles, is there any relationship between the value calculated for $Z$ and the respective ones calculated for $A, B, C$ and $D$?**

for example
$$\exists? f_{Var}(x) \vert Var(Z)\simeq f_{Var}(Var(A), Var(B), Var(C), Var(D))$$

Do other functions $f_{Q_{10}}...f_{Q_x}$ exist to express relationships for quantiles?

Being the 1000 values randomly distributed in the 4 subsets, I assume the answer, if any, is not precise but should contain a confidence interval instead.

Comment: You should use mathjax to properly format your math formulas on this site. People will pay more attention to you if you do.

Comment: @araomis, thank you. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the variance for the full set from the means and variances of the subsets, for example using the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) (the mean of the variances plus the variance of the means)

So $$\text{Var}(Z) = \frac{100\,\text{Var}(A) + 200 \, \text{Var}(B) + 350 \,\text{Var}(C) + 350 \,\text{Var}(D)}{1000} \\+ \frac{100\,\text{mean}(A)^2 + 200 \, \text{mean}(B)^2 + 350 \,\text{mean}(C)^2 + 350 \,\text{mean}(D)^2}{1000} \\- \left(\frac{100\,\text{mean}(A) + 200 \, \text{mean}(B) + 350 \,\text{mean}(C) + 350 \,\text{mean}(D)}{1000}\right)^2$$

There is no such equations for the quantiles without the full data; there may be weak and complicated inequalities but I suspect you will find they are unlikely to be useful in practice.

Comment: Thank you, @Henry. It looks like what I was searching for (at least for the variance)